# What is the default font family of a WPF application?

Tags: .net, wpf

What is the default font family of a WPF application? Is this system dependent? I found **Tahoma** on my system.

If I create a control then what will be the default fontfamily of control is set?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The "default" font is the current system font of your current OS. Tahoma is the default system font of Windows XP, on Vista, Windows 7 it is Segoe UI.

Comment: That is the default font you *type* with but not the font of the UI (i.e. the font used in the menues and buttons of Word).

Comment: Any idea for Windows 8?

Comment: Segoe UI is also default in Win10 and Win11

Answer (score 4):

On Windows 8, it seems like the fallback font is Segoe UI with a 0.9 baseline and 1.2 line spacing.

[image: Simulating WPF default font]

```
  <Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Page.Resources>
      <clr:String x:Key="someText">The quick brown fox, ABCD, 1234567890, /@#</clr:String>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="lightColor">#bbbbbb</SolidColorBrush>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="darkColor">#000000</SolidColorBrush>
      <FontFamily x:Key="default">non existent font</FontFamily>
      <FontFamily x:Key="segoe">Segoe UI</FontFamily>
      <FontFamily x:Key="segoe_base" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/composite-font"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
              xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
              Baseline="0.9"
              LineSpacing="1.2">
        <FontFamily.FamilyNames>
          <s:String x:Key="en-US" >Baseline Segoe UI</s:String>
        </FontFamily.FamilyNames>
        <FontFamily.FamilyMaps>
          <FontFamilyMap Target="Segoe UI" />
        </FontFamily.FamilyMaps>
      </FontFamily>
    </Page.Resources>

    <StackPanel Margin="10" Width="250">
      <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">Segoe UI with a baseline of 0.9 and line spacing of 1.2 lines up with the default font</TextBlock>
      <Grid Margin="5">  
        <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource darkColor}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" FontFamily="{StaticResource default}" Text="{StaticResource someText}"/>
        <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource lightColor}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" FontFamily="{StaticResource segoe_base}" Text="{StaticResource someText}"/>
      </Grid>
      <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap">Segoe UI with the default baseline and line spacing does not line up with the default font</TextBlock>
      <Grid Margin="5">  
        <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource darkColor}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" FontFamily="{StaticResource default}" Text="{StaticResource someText}"/>
        <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource lightColor}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" FontFamily="{StaticResource segoe}" Text="{StaticResource someText}"/>
      </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
  </Page>
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this font family comes from `SystemFonts.MessageFontFamily` static property. So if you ever need to use it somewhere in your app - you should read it from there instead of constructing the new `FontFamily` instance by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can take it from default value of `DependencyProperty`. For example, you create custom control, which will be draw text using DrawingContext and you want set default value for FontFamily, you can declare `DependencyProperty` such way:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FontFamilyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(FontFamily), typeof(FontFamily), typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(TextBlock.FontFamilyProperty.DefaultMetadata.DefaultValue, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public FontFamily FontFamily
    {
        get => (FontFamily)GetValue(FontFamilyProperty);
        set => SetValue(FontFamilyProperty, value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question correctly, Segoe UI is the default FontFamily for WPF apllications.